# Thymeleaf: Spring-Security: Error during execution of processor 'AuthorizeAttrProcessor'

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

**I get this error when I enter thymeleaf page that utilizes sec:authorize**

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.processor.AuthorizeAttrProcessor' 
>   .....
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

**Relevant dependencies are:**

```html
 <properties>
  <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
 </properties>




    <!--  security -->
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
     <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
  <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
 </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-spring4</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

**Relevant Thymeleaf code is:**

```html
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
  <a style="color:#555555" href="./logout" th:text="#{label.logout}">Logout</a>
</div>
```

**Relevant XML configuuration is**

```html
        
            
    <!-- Thymeleaf Template Engine -->        
        <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">        
         <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />        
         <property name="additionalDialects">        
            <set>        
             <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.tiles2.dialect.TilesDialect" />        
             <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>         
           </set>        
         </property>        
        </bean>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that you need to specify the Context Loader Listener in web.xml.THis is not thymeleaf related. It is simply spring config

```html
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/*_applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and the listener:

```html
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```